# How to show an error when a field is left unfilled by the user?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

So, I have successfully made a registration form. And now I want to work on UX of the Registration form, so when I purposely leave a field in the form unfilled it should give the box a red border, which it gives for Company Name, Name, E-mail, Password. But not for categories and sub categories. I click the proceed button and it just remains as it is, it should show a red border on that field too. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

This is my blade code:

```
   $('#btnProceedStep1').click(function(){
    var companyname = $('#company_name').val();
    var geniename = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var cpassword = $('#cpassword').val();
    var isError = 0;
    var errorList = [];
    
    var categories = [];var subcategories = [];

    $. each($(".category:checked"), function(){
        categories.push($(this). val());
    });
    var category = categories.join(",");
    
    $. each($(".subcategory:checked"), function(){
        subcategories.push($(this). val());
    });
    var subcategory = categories.join(",");
    
    if(companyname.trim() == ""){
        $('#company_name').addClass('error');
        isError = 1;
        errorList.push(1);
    }else{
        $('#company_name').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }

    if(geniename.trim() == ""){
        $('#name').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{            
        $('#name').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(email.trim() == ""){
        $('#email').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        if(!validateEmail(email)){
            return false;
        }
        $('#email').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(mobile.trim() == ""){
        $('#mobile').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        if(mobile.length > 10 || mobile.length < 10){
            notif({
                msg: "Invalid mobile number, mobile number should be 10 digit.",
                type: "error",
                position: "center",
                timeout: 5000
            });
            return false;
        }
        $('#mobile').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(categories.length <= 0){
        $('#category').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        $('#category').removeClass('error');  
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(subcategories.length <= 0){
        $('#subcategory').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        $('#subcategory').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(password.trim() == ""){
        $('#password').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        if(password.length < 6){
            errorList.push(1);
            isError = 1;
            notif({
                msg: "Password must be 6 characters/digits long",
                type: "error",
                position: "center",
                timeout: 5000
            });
        }
        $('#password').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(cpassword.trim() == ""){
        $('#cpassword').addClass('error');
        errorList.push(1);
        isError = 1;
    }else{
        $('#cpassword').removeClass('error');
        isError = 0;
    }
    
    if(errorList.length > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(password != cpassword){
            notif({
                msg: "Password and confirm password are mismatched, please check",
                type: "error",
                position: "center",
                timeout: 5000
            });
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#step01').fadeOut(500);
            $("#step02").fadeIn(800);
        }
    }
});
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remember to also validate the backend, don't just validate the client side.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery validation it will check rules before submit

> [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

> [normal jquery validation](https://formden.com/blog/validate-contact-form-jquery)